# How Mule 4 works with CA signed certificate

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, mulesoft, mule4, tls1.3

We all know how a self signed certificate is configured in mulesoft. We generate a key pair and configure the trustore in the http listener.

But the question is how the actual CA signed certificate is configured in the application? The certificate will only have the public key of the server signed by CA's private key.

Can anyone help here

Trying to understand how and where the SSL certificate signed by a valid CA is configured in mule4 apps

Answer (score 0):

That's the same that with any other certificate. The keystore file will contain a certificate. If the certificate is signed by a well known Certificate Authority then a chain of intermediate signing certificate authorities will  be included with the certificate, until a certificate signed by a known CA which Java can validate against it's CA list (in it's cacerts file).